# Partition of an integer given constraints

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Here I would like to ask how do you count the number of partitions of an integer, e.g. 12, given the **partition size can only be 5** and $ 1\leq \text{the value of each partition} \leq5$.

I can only count each individual case by hand through writing each case, but I sometimes forget to include other possible cases. Is there any quick and useful technique to count each individual case of the partition of an integer **by hand only**?

Comment: Are the partitions distinct with respect to order?  In other words, is the partition of $12$ into $(5, 5, 2)$ distinct from its partition into $(2, 5, 5)$?

Comment: @BrianTung (5,5,2) is the same as (2,5,5); note that the partition size in my question is 5 and the value of each partition is more than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 5.

Comment: You write that "the value of each partition" is between $1$ and $5$; I'm assuming that you mean the value of each part.

The ordinary generating function for these partitions is

$$
\frac1{5!}\left.\frac{\partial^5}{\partial y^5}\prod_{j=1}^5\sum_{k=0}^5y^kx^{jk}\right|_{y=0}\;.
$$

Wolfram|Alpha computes this as

$$
x^5(x^{20}+x^{19}+2x^{18}+3x^{17}+5x^{16}+6x^{15}+8x^{14}+9x^{13}+11x^{12}+11x^{11} \\+12x^{10}+11x^9+11x^8+9x^7+8x^6+6x^5+5x^4+3x^3+2x^2+x+1)\;.
$$

Note the symmetry about $x^{15}$, which arises from replacing each part $m$ by $6-m$.

Comment: I originally posted this as an answer but then noticed that you emphasized you want to count quickly by hand and this would be somewhat tedious. I'm not sure whether you'll find something quicker, though. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5E5%2Fdy%5E5%5B%5Cprod_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5E5%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E5y%5Ekx%5E%7Bjk%7D%5D%20where%20y%3D0)'s the Wolfram|Alpha computation.

Comment: First observe that the number of partitions of any positive integer $n$ into parts in which the largest part is at most $m$ is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ into at most $m$ parts. Call this number $p_m (n).$ The generating function for such partition is $$f(x) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{m} \frac {1} {1 - x^n},\ 0 < x < 1.$$ By Taylor's theorem $f(x)$ can be expanded as follows $:$ $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} p_m (n) x^n.$$ You need to evaluate $p_5(n),$ for any positive integer $n.$ Right?

Comment: So actually $p_m (n) = \frac  {f^{(n)} (0)} {n!}.$

Comment: For $n = 12$ and $m=5$ define $f_5 (x) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{5} \frac {1} {1 - x^n}.$ Then $$p_5 (12) = \frac {f_5^{(12)} (0)} {(12)!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For a small number such as 12, the simplest way is to manually make cases. This is an example:

**Case 1**: all the partitions are equal. Only one partition i.e. $(4,4,4)$ exists

**Case 2**: 2 partitions are equal. if the numbers are $(a,b,b)$ then $a,b$ are solutions of $2b+a=12$, $1\le a,b \le 5, a \ne b$. Only $(2,5,5)$ satisfies this.

**Case 3**: all the partitions are different. If the numbers are $(a,b,c)$ then $a,b,c$ are solutions of $a+b+c=12$, $1\le a,b,c \le 5, a \ne b \ne c$. $(3,4,5)$ satisfies this condition.

The only partitions possible are $(2,5,5)$, $(3,4,5)$ and $(4,4,4)$.

Note that the techniques I used above are similar to Multinomial theorem, but not exactly same. This is because you mentioned that $(2,5,5)$ is the same as $(5,2,5)$ or $(5,5,2)$. If these cases are different, then multinomial theorem can be used. For larger numbers with more partitions, this technique gets complicated and you should use the generating function described in the comments.

Comment: What about $(3,4,5)$?

Comment: yep missed that. edited. Not a good idea to do math so early in the morning :P

Comment: You compute partitions of $12$ into $3$ parts. What about partitions with more than $3$ parts?